# change base class pointer content without allocate new address

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, arduino

I'm working on an Arduino project with limited memory capacity, so many C++ magical conveniences are out of the window, one of them is being able to allocate memory anywhere you want (can cause [Heap Fragmentation](https://cpp4arduino.com/2018/11/06/what-is-heap-fragmentation.html) if you do that). But OOP needs pointers and allocation:

```
class StateBase
{
  virtual run();
};
class StateA : public StateBase
{
  int bigArr[100];
  virtual run();
};
//About 5 more States, with different member variables
//Usually in Arduino, you allocate a big chunk of heap memory, and keep reusing it:
StateBase *memPool[] = {new StateA(), new StateB(), new...};
```

But I want to try this one, and to my surprise, it works:

```
StateBase *memPool = new StateBase();
//...do something, now I need to switch state
StateA newState;
memcpy(memPool, &newState, sizeof(StateA));
```

Questions:

1. Is this a bad idea? Does it have any consequences?
2. should you use `memPool = new (memPool) StateA()` instead of memcpy?
3. Why does it work, clearly StateBase and StateA have different size?

Comment: You would be writing past the allocated memory since StateA is much larger than StateBase.  It is *allowed* but it isn't *working* since you could be overwriting other data.  Eventually when accessing that data you'll have problems.

Answer (score 1):

1. It's an utterly bad idea and the consequence is [*undefined behavior*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).
2. You should use the copy/move constructors/assignment operators and trust the compiler and OS to do a decent job until you have reason not to.
3. They *are* of different sizes (`sizeof`). See the consequence in 1.
4. When you switch state like that you are probably doing a pessimization preventing the compiler from doing something cleaver.

You could use a `union`-like structure (let's call it [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)) to do something similar and still use the implicit move assignment etc. If the types in your classes are trivial, the compiler will know how to do it efficiently. If the types are *not* trivial what you're doing will most probably make the undefined behavior behave in more noticable ways. See [*Nasal Demons*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

[image]

<sup>N'os - Summoner of Nasal Demons - Picture credit to [Billyonion64 @ Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/user/Billyonion64/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, it is. You'll probably damage some other objects since *StateA* is bigger then memory you are coping it in.
2. Placement new usually more reasonable but in this case it doesn't change much. You still have big problem from point 1.
3. It work because function like *memcpy* doesn't care about memory management. So if you want to shoot your leg, here they are. :) It almost always bad idea to use functions from **string.h** (cstring) in modern C++.

Answer (score 0):

Although it might appear work, it's a bad idea for several reasons.  For one because the compiler can do various optimizations, your code may break unexpectedly. More importantly you are wiping out part of the heap so it's likely only a matter of time before your program crashes. This isn't even close to being safe even if you are not so sensitive about using undefined behavior. There are certain times you can do stuff that is technically UB but generally works, but given you are overwriting un-allocated memory, this isn't one of those times.

If you are really so worried about fragmentation you can in fact use your option 2 and do a placement new, however whatever memory buffer you use should be big enough for the largest class object you are going to use it for. Also I wouldn't new one object and then new over it with another. That's messy. Just allocate your buffer separately with malloc or whatever, and then use placement new on that address. When you are done with your object call the destructor explicitly, and you can then reuse your memory with another placement new. Rinse and repeat.